# Dropbox-similar software that runs on Windows XP

Tags: windows, file-synchronization, synchronization, windows-xp

I need to find a software running all the time in background that can watch a folder (e.g. `D:\DATA\`) and each time:

- a file is modified
- a new file is created
- a file is deleted

then the file will be automatically updated/uploaded to a cloud storage, without user interaction (done quietly in background task).

The software has to be working on Windows XP (it's for a computer - not mine - that I cannot update soon). Neither Dropbox nor Google Drive support XP anymore.

**Would you have a recommendation?**

PS: I've read [this topic](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/50bc5f/dropbox_dropped_windows_xp_need_a_workaround_any/) but not sure which one still applies/which one works well.

Answer (score 2):

From softonic.com

> Cloud storage is all the rage, but some offerings have complicated web
>   access and force you to download / upload manually in order to save
>   your files. Enter MegaSync. [Mega](https://mega.nz/) has created their synchronization
>   tool to sync files stored in the cloud to any number of local devices.
>   Any edits completed on a local device is then uploaded, automatically,
>   and backed up to the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out [Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/) or [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) (an Owncloud fork) on your server-side. They are both open source and have free editions as well, well documented, supported, used by many big companies (e.g. Fujifilm, Siemens, Daimler) and universities around the world and are self hosted as well as available solutions from many providers.

You can also find a ready to go appliance for both of them on [Turnkeylinux](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/owncloud) (also great for testing purposes, just drop it into Virtualbox to try it out).

We're using it for years and it's awesome, because it's really fast, lightweight and easy to use.
The Owncloud-Sync-Client **doesn't** support Win XP, however, both softwares provide WebDAV support out of the box and you can connect to WebDAV via WinXP using all the onboard tools (offline availability etc.) for synchronisation. Or you could use a sync tool like  [Allway Sync](https://allwaysync.com/), which still works for Win XP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have trouble doing this directly, because pretty much NO ONE is supporting XP at this point. Given it's lengthy list of security problems, and the fact that MS won't support it anymore, one can't blame the vendors on this one.

Now, what I would do to make this work is add a second computer, running Windows 10. 
The XP computer should have a shared folder where it writes the files. 
The Win 10 computer should automatically mount that shared folder, and should run Dropbox. 
The Dropbox client should be configured such that the Dropbox directory is on the XP Shared folder.

Thus, the XP box will update files. Dropbox on Win 10 will eventually notice the changes, and upload the files.

Comment: This isn't an answer / recommendation for the question. However it's nice to encourage people to use new versions of Windows.

Comment: Sorry but I already know all of that, I personally updated all my computers. But here I need to find a solution for a specific computer that cannot be updated soon. So this is not really an answer. Thank you anyway for posting!

Answer (score 0):

Sync from sync.com at this time still works perfectly on my home XP network. Initial storage is free. Support used to be wonderful, even for the free users, but this seems no longer the case.